# Capture VM Image Operation via Azure Rest API

Tags: rest, azure

I am trying  [Capture VM Image operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn499768.aspx) using Azure Management Rest API. I continue to get following error every time I perform the operation

```
<OperationId>26818000-9c8e-80e6-8a94-558c4d0f442c</OperationId>
<OperationObjectId>/3dc34e96-8d19-483b-8eaa-d79248e56391/services/hostedservices/bhathiya409-vmimageapilivetest/deployments/bhathiya409-vmimageapilivetest/roleinstances/bhathiya409-vmimageapilivetest/Operations</OperationObjectId>
<OperationName>ExecuteRoleOperation</OperationName>
<OperationParameters xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceManagement">
    <OperationParameter>
        <d2p1:Name>serviceName</d2p1:Name>
        <d2p1:Value>bhathiya409-vmimageapilivetest</d2p1:Value>
    </OperationParameter>
    <OperationParameter>
        <d2p1:Name>deploymentName</d2p1:Name>
        <d2p1:Value>bhathiya409-vmimageapilivetest</d2p1:Value>
    </OperationParameter>
    <OperationParameter>
        <d2p1:Name>roleInstanceName</d2p1:Name>
        <d2p1:Value>bhathiya409-vmimageapilivetest</d2p1:Value>
    </OperationParameter>
    <OperationParameter>
        <d2p1:Name>roleOperation</d2p1:Name>
        <d2p1:Value i:nil="true" />
    </OperationParameter>
</OperationParameters>
<OperationStatus>
    <ID>26818000-9c8e-80e6-8a94-558c4d0f442c</ID>
    <Status>Failed</Status>
    <HttpStatusCode>500</HttpStatusCode>
    <Error>
        <Code>InternalError</Code>
        <Message>The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request.</Message>
    </Error>
</OperationStatus>
<OperationStartedTime>2015-03-30T22:33:55Z</OperationStartedTime>
<OperationCompletedTime>2015-03-30T22:34:00Z</OperationCompletedTime>
<OperationKind>CaptureRoleAsVMImageOperation</OperationKind>
```

Comment: How do you try to perform the operation? Do you send a manual REST call or you use Powershell?

Comment: I used REST calls. Looks like I have found the problem (mistake).Thanks
@PanagiotisKefalidis

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in OSState Attribute whre I was paasing invalid value.

Possible values are:
Generalized, 
Specialized

I think these options are case sensitive.